# Set administrator privileges to subprocess.check_call() in Python

Tags: python, windows

I call two executables from a python script one which needs Administrator privileges and one which does not need them. Is there any way by which I can set the Administrator privilege before executing the executable so that it does not ask me for my password.

My script is as follows

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['DoesnotNeedAdminPrivilege.exe'])
subprocess.check_call(['NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'])
```

I tried to run this script from cmd by starting the cmd to run as an Adminstrator. Is there any way to pass these admin rights to the second executable so that it works without any problem

Comment: Can you run the initial python call with admin privileges and enter the credentials just before run time?

Comment: subprocess.check_call(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe']) ?

Comment: I want to convert this .py file into an .exe file. So I just want to run this converted .exe file as an administrator, which should cause the second subprocess call to run as an admin. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a nasty workaround

```
    f = open('test.cmd', 'w+')
    f.write("execute.exe")
    f.close()

    os.system("runas /savecred /profile /user:Administrator \"test.cmd\"")
```

or you can use subprocess

Answer (score 1):

Try this out for entering an administrative password.

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.check_call(['DoesnotNeedAdminPrivilege.exe'])
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```

Here are the docs on:

Popen - http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

runas - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

if this works will depend on the program NeedsAdminPrivilege.

Comment: I will be better if I dont have to enter the password..Is there any way to avoid letting user put the password ?

Comment: Speaking about the code in your question:  Both children should have gotten Admin priv's whether they needed them or not, IF you started the script with admin priv's in the first place.  So ... could you answer JonathanV's question?  All other answers are a hack (running my answer or turning off UAC)

Comment: @Back2Basics, I'm trying to put this piece of code to work without success. Are you sure it works?

Comment: I forgot to alias subprocess as sp other than that I use this all the time.