# Rum cmd from python subprocess module with admin privileges

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I would like to know if there is any way to run a cmd process using subprocess module in python(Using Popen) with admin privileges. I need to run some conmmand that must have admin privileges in order to run correctly.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set administrator privileges to subprocess.check\_call() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505893/set-administrator-privileges-to-subprocess-check-call-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

from the link

[Set administrator privileges to subprocess.check_call() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505893/set-administrator-privileges-to-subprocess-check-call-in-python)

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.check_call(['DoesnotNeedAdminPrivilege.exe'])
prog = sp.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', 'NeedsAdminPrivilege.exe'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```