# Python cmd command sfc /scannow

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

Hello so I'm trying to make a basic python script to execute cmd commands. The `DISM` command works fine, but when I try the `sfc` command I get the message:

> Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service."

I am executing this script with admin privileges on cmd:

```
import subprocess
from os import system
print('1. sfc scan')
print('2. DISM')

key = int(input('Input your choice: '))
if key == 1:
    system("sfc /scannow")
elif key == 2:
    system("DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth")
```

Answer (score 0):

bases on [this answer from Back2Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506390/4464653), you can try calling it as admin using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen( ['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'sfc /scannow'] )
```

Comment: Hello that is an interesting script but wouldn't that be problematic is there is no user called Administrator and the user's profile runs as admin?