# Different behaviour of command launched from subprocess and from prompt

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, device-manager

I'm trying to open the driver properties of a usb device from my python script.
In Microsoft website I've found how can do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/invoking-a-device-properties-dialog-box-from-a-command-line-prompt

If I launch the command from command prompt, all works fine, but if I launch the same command from a python script, the driver property window appear, but the button for escalate the user and enable the "driver update function" does not work. If I click the button it do nothing.
To launch the program from python I use this code:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'rundll32.exe devmgr.dll,DeviceProperties_RunDLL /DeviceID \"USB\\VID_0A12&PID_4010\\6&2396E77A&4&3\"'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS, close_fds=True)
```

Someone know what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user rights of the subprocess are not the same as the CLI process. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505893/set-administrator-privileges-to-subprocess-check-call-in-python) help?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've tryed but without success. 
Anyway, it's a non sense to ask the user to put his password for an action that it can do without any problem if launched from command line. Maybe a "runas /sameuser" command will be the solution :)